# built-in laptop webcam shows complete purple screen

Tags: laptop, webcam, camera, hp-laptop

My laptop is : HP EliteBook 8540w 
I'm now running on windows 10 --the same problem existed on windows 7--.

My problem is that when I run my camera , it shows nothing but a purple noisy screen , at first I though the camera has been damaged after the last time my laptop has fallen on the ground , but I found that the camera works well when I keep pressing the upper edge of the camera .

When I press on the upper edge of the camera , the screen goes up a little bit  and the purple color goes away --at least I can see myself clearly-- .

I suspect that lens of my camera has been shifted from its place ,and that's why it works when I keep pressing the upper edge of it .

Anyone could could help illustrate the problem  and how to fix it ?
Thanks in advance.
Please if you need more info/screenshots ,leave a comment . And I'm sorry if I missed any detail I should have mentioned.

and here is some screenshots :

Before/after I keep pressing on the top edge

[at first run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otlkU.jpg)

[while pressing and holding the top of the webcam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjmLK.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you need to replace the webcam module, HP P/N 583219-001, since when you press near the camera it works that is indicative of a bad connection, either in the cable or most likely on the camera module itself.

Look at document page 28 (PDF page 35), Display Components, of the [Service Manual](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=4096175&docLocale=en_US&docId=emr_na-c03382696) for this laptop. This document also clearly shows the process for disassembly and replacement of the module.

There is a chance that you could disassemble the display and find the camera module is out of position somehow and you can readjust it, but I personally think that is unlikely. This is clearly not a driver/software issue.